# Conditional FilterQuery in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to conditionally execute a FilterQuery (fq)?

In other words: Only execute it if a certain condition is true.

Example:

I have multiple cities and their geolocation in my solr database. And I additionally store wheter they are important. Now I want to query all cities in a certain range of a geolocation but also always return the important cities.

Or in SQL-like Syntax (***I know it's horrible and not even correct SQL***, but it explains my needs):

```
select *
from cities
having distance(cityname, 30, 30) or important(cityname)
```

So far I haven't found anything like that. I could do that in a custom filter query but I'd rather not want to do that :).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Realworld-like thing I want to use it for:

```
{!geofilt pt=30.2,23.0 sfield=locationCoordinates d=20 cost=20} or nationWide:true
```

EDIT2:

Solution:

```
map(query({!geofilt pt=20.3,30.2 sfield=locationCoordinates d=1}, -1), -1, -1,   nationWide:true)
```

Negative values should be ok to use in this scenario:
http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-search-relevancy.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [FunctionQuery](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery). There are pre-built functions available or you could [write a custom Function Query](http://www.supermind.org/blog/756/how-to-write-a-custom-solr-functionquery).

Since you mention city, I am tempted to point you to the [Geohash function](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#geohash_-_Convert_to_geohash), but am not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that with the given example?

Comment: geohash isn't really what i need.

Comment: Could you express your distance calculation in a math formula? I am not very good at this calculation.

Comment: Hmmm now I know what you want. You want me to write the calculation of the distance by hand?

Comment: Yeah sort of. If you were writing this in SQL, you would have to do something similar (i.e write your `distance` function, to return a value that you can compare against). Querying SOLR is similar, only the syntax varies.

Comment: Unless of course, that is a big calculation, in which case I would prefer storing computed values in SOLR index, which I can run simpler queries.

Comment: map(query({!geofilt pt=20.3,30.2 sfield=locationCoordinates d=1}, -1), -1, -1, nationWide:true) I am doing this now. :)

Comment: one more question: what is the range of solr scores? Can they be negative?

Comment: I am fairly certain that the scores are always positive, but can be decimals. But I can't find any documentation confirming this.

Comment: What I have seen on google is that it's being normed between 0 and 1:
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Filter-by-relevance-td1837486.html
(3rd posting)